# iOS Click push message can not jump to app

Tags: ios, crash, push

I encountered a very difficult problem: click to push can not enter the App.

The first case: do not kill App, let it hang in the background, send a push message, No matter how long, click on the push message is to enter the App.

The second case: kill App, and then send the push message, if about 5 minutes or less, you can call up App; if more than 5 minutes, it can not afford to call APP.

I can not get APP crash log, can only get the system log.I compared the normal and non-normal system log. In the system log can not evoke the APP found the following information:

```
<Notice>: 12672 com.hori.xxxxx: Unknown (most elevated: Unknown)
<Notice>: 12672 com.hori.xxxxx: Terminated (most elevated: Terminated)
<Notice>: Entry, display name com.hori.xxxxx uuid (null) pid 12672 isFront 0
<Notice>: Duplicate removal of display name com.hori.xxxxx
<Notice>: Entry, display name com.hori.xxxxx uuid (null) pid 12672 isFront 0
<Notice>: Duplicate removal of display name com.hori.xxxxx
<Notice>: Entry, display name com.hori.xxxxx uuid (null) pid 12672 isFront 0
<Notice>: Duplicate removal of display name com.hori.xxxxx
```

I can not find the relevant information on the Internet, please help me, thank you.

Comment: you mean say after 5 min notification will not come?

Comment: Notification can be received, but kill APP, wait about 5 minutes and then click the notification message, then enter the LaunchScreen after the APP immediately flashed.